# Instantiation with C# "dynamic" Keyword

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, instantiation, keyword

I've seen many examples of this tool which abstracts away the cumbersome syntax of Reflection.  However none demonstrate instantiation of an unknown type.  Is it safe to assume this isn't possible with "dynamic"?

Comment: which tool are you talking about?

Comment: and how does it "abstract away the syntax of Reflection"?

Comment: One is able to assume the existence of properties and methods rather than use Reflection as the middle man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logically, it's impossible to instantiate an *unknown* type -- to instantiate a type, *something* must know what it is.

`dynamic` is useful for *manipulating* values of an unknown type (by assuming that it is capable of certain operations, which will fail at runtime if they are in fact not possible).  To *instantiate* any type, however, you either need to use compile-time instantiation (e.g. using a C# constructor call), or else you need an instance of `Type` that corresponds to your desired type.

Comment: I think this answer is a bit misleading... I would guess that the reasons you can't do something like "dynamic var = new SomeNamespace.SomeClass(...)", are due to implementation details in the compiler/runtime, rather than there being a fault in the general concept.  I don't think there is anything stopping someone from writing a function like "Construct(params Object[] args)" that does what the OP is after here.

Comment: @Aaron: But you would still either need that `Construct` method to either be (1) parameterized by the desired type (meaning that the type must be known at compile time) or (2) take a `Type` object as a parameter, meaning that the type must be known at runtime, or (3) take a string which gets passed to `Type.GetType` (after which it's the same as #2). That's what I meant by "*something* must know what it is".

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I had a typo above- I had intended `Construct(string typeName, params Object[] args)` as the signature.  I can't speak for the OP, but I assumed he/she did know what type they wanted to instantiate, just like you would need to know the name of the method you want to call when you call a method `dynamic`ally.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler can use the dynamic keyword so that the dlr will construct a type, but it's designed to late bind the arguments of a constructor rather than the type to be constructed.  The opensource framework [ImpromptuInterface](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/) abstracts the [dlr calls, including the constructor](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#Basic).  If you need to call a constructor that has arguments this will run about 5 times faster than using reflection/Activator.

```
var x = Impromptu.InvokeConstructor(Type.GetType("SomeType"),args...);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what your goal is... but do you mean something like

```
dynamic X = Type.GetType("SomeUnknownType").GetConstructor(null).Invoke(null);
```

?

the above just calls the default (parameterless) constructor of the Type `"SomeUnknownType"` and assign the resulting instance to a `dynamic` .

Comment: I mean something like "dynamic X = dynamic.GetInstance("SomeUnknownType");".  And perhaps an overload that passes in constructor parameters.